# EVI differences between Landsat 5 and 8 (utilizing Collection 2 data within Google Earth Engine)

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, evi

I am calculating the EVI changes from 1984 to 2023 in the winter months within the state of Maine. I have written up a script to understand the changes within each month across the 40-year time scale which produces a chart showing the average EVI within each month (December, January, February, March, and April) across that time frame.

[image]

I am noticing some EVI changes from Landsat 5 (1984-2011) to Landsat 8 (2012-2022) that do not seem naturally occurring. I have been scouring forums and noticed that this is very common with Collection 1 Landsat datasets (for metrics such as EVI, NDVI, etc.) that requires a harmonization process but for Collection 2, you supposedly do not need to harmonize the datasets (https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/faq#is_cross-sensor_landsat_surface_reflectance_harmonization_needed).

Has anyone dealt with something similar to this before?

I would run Collection 1 and harmonize the products to compare to Collection 2 however Google Earth Engine does not have Collection 1 products in their catalog.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Here is a link to my code directly: https://code.earthengine.google.com/eed2f24f86ef03613c1183a826e6e938

Comment: This is a fascinating question. The aim isn't for debugging purposes, so I disagree with closing this question. I suggest you to find sort of invariant pixels (which is often a difficult task) and compare EVI from both sensors